# No DiscoveryClient found during Spring bootstrap of cloud-vault-config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul, spring-cloud-vault-config

I'm using `spring-cloud-starter-vault-config` to pull secrets from vault. I'm able to get this working just fine with Config First Bootstrap. When I try and enable service discovery so I can get the vault instances from consul, I get an Error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapPropertySourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' parameter 0
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The Consul auto config just doesn't seem to be firing at all in the bootstrap phase of startup.

I believe I've set all the right properties in my bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app-name
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
    vault:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: vault
      authentication: approle
      app-role:
        role-id: my-role-id
        secret-id: my-secret-id
      kv:
        enabled: true
        application-name: ${spring.application.name}
      fail-fast: true
      scheme: http
```

Is there a property or some annotation I'm missing to enable consul during bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention **Config First Bootstrap** (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#config-first-bootstrap), that means you are using Spring Cloud Config over Spring Cloud Consul Config?

If so, you also need to include

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-discovery</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If using Spring Cloud Consul Config instead of Spring Cloud Config (see [Difference between spring cloud config server vs consul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397295/difference-between-spring-cloud-config-server-vs-consul) and [Spring Cloud Consul Config over Spring Cloud Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749034/spring-cloud-consul-config-over-spring-cloud-config) for discussions on the differences), you may still run into this problem.

**Below is for cases when Spring Cloud Consul Config is being used:**

There's no mention of the spring cloud version, but looking at version 3.0.0, I see that the bootstrap section of spring.factories used for auto configuration does not include the file **ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration**. This is the Configuration file that exports the **DiscoveryClient** bean (ConsulDiscoveryClient extends DiscoveryClient).

```
public class ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration {

  ...

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public ConsulDiscoveryClient consulDiscoveryClient(ConsulClient consulClient,
      ConsulDiscoveryProperties discoveryProperties) {
    return new ConsulDiscoveryClient(consulClient, discoveryProperties);
  }

}
```

**ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration** is included in the regular # Auto-Configuration section as you can see below, but that phase happens after the # Bootstrap Configuration phase. These are the relevant spring.factories files

org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-vault-config/3.0.0/spring-cloud-vault-config-3.0.0.jar!/META-INF/spring.factories

```
# Auto-Configuration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultReactiveAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration

# Bootstrap Configuration
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.DiscoveryClientVaultBootstrapConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.ReactiveDiscoveryClientVaultBootstrapConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultReactiveBootstrapConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapPropertySourceConfiguration

# ConfigData Resolver
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolver=\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigDataLocationResolver

# ConfigData Loader
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoader=\
org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigDataLoader
```

org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-consul-discovery/3.0.0/spring-cloud-consul-discovery-3.0.0.jar!/META-INF/spring.factories

```
# Auto-Configuration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.configclient.ConsulConfigServerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.serviceregistry.ConsulAutoServiceRegistrationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.serviceregistry.ConsulServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.reactive.ConsulReactiveDiscoveryClientConfiguration,\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulCatalogWatchAutoConfiguration, \
org.springframework.cloud.consul.support.ConsulHeartbeatAutoConfiguration

# Bootstrap Configuration
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.configclient.ConsulDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration

org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper=\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.configclient.ConsulConfigServerBootstrapper
```

As you can see, the # Bootstrap Configuration in spring-cloud-vault-config includes the right Vault Configuration files, but the # Bootstrap Configuration in spring-cloud-consul-discovery only includes **ConsulDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration**, which seems to be there for cases when someone chooses Spring Cloud Config instead of Spring Cloud Consul Config. I say this because the file is conditional on **ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.class**

```
@ConditionalOnClass(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled")
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ImportAutoConfiguration({ ConsulAutoConfiguration.class, ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration.class,
    ConsulReactiveDiscoveryClientConfiguration.class })
public class ConsulDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration {

}
```

which is found in spring-cloud-config-client-3.0.0.jar. If you were to include the spring-cloud-config-client dependency, Vault service discovery would work, since it includes

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration({ ... ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration.class })
```

the exact Configuration file needed. The problem is, if you include spring-cloud-config-client, you'd now be using both Spring Cloud Consul Config **and** Spring Cloud Config, which is likely not what you want (both are enabled by **spring.cloud.discovery.enabled**, so attempting to include both dependencies and switching one off may be tricky).

Ok, so from what I see above, this looks like a bug in Spring Cloud Consul. I didn't see any other spring.factories that could potentially load **ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration** in the Bootstrap Configuration section. If there exists some other dependency that is needed that will do this, I haven't seen it.

As a temporary workaround until the problem is fixed in Spring Cloud Consul, you can add your own **src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories** file to a module in your project and include

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulDiscoveryClientConfiguration
```

It solves the problem in spring cloud version 3.0.0.